# .count troubles, variable wont count correctly

Tags: python, counting

I was doing a coding challenge, and I can't seem to figure out why the count function allways gives my "5" as my output. Here is my code:

```
print("Welcome to the Love Calculator!")
name1 = input("What is your name? \n")
name2 = input("What is their name? \n")
n1 = str(name1 .lower)
n2 = str(name2 .lower)
print(n1 .count("t"))
```

Comment: For name1, `n1 = name1.lower()` and the same for name2. The parenthesis are needed for `lower()`

Comment: Your code `n1 = str(name1 .lower)` is capturing the text: `<built-in method lower of str object at 0x10421a770> 52`.  Then your code `print(n1 .count("t"))` is counting the number of times the letter "t" exists in the `n1` variable.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't calling the lower function right. It has to be `name1.lower()` and `name2.lower()`. You also don't need the space between variable name and function. To call a function you need brackets `()`.